# LINQ and DataTable query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following in a datatable:

```
58,10,251,3
58,10,251,1
58,10,251,1
58,10,251,2
58,10,261,1
60,11,666111,1
```

I would like to get the following results:

```
251,7
261,1

666111,1
```

This is what I'm playing with so far I think I almost have it but not entirely sure how to end it....

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable().Where(h => h.Field<string>("COLUMN 0") == val) 
            group row by row.Field<string>("COLUMN 2") 
            into sales 
            orderby sales.Key 
            select new 
            { 
                Name = sales.Key, 
                CountOfClients = sales.Sum(v => sales.Count()) 
            };
```

This gives me

251,16
261,1
666111,1

So it works for 261 and 666111 but not the 251.

Somehow the 8 got doubled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sales.Sum(v => sales.Count())
```

This is wrong. You're summing the count of sales. This is the same as `sales.Count() * sales.Count()`.

You should be writing something like `sales.Sum(v => v.Field<int>("COLUMN 4"))` or something similar, based on your previous queries.

That is:

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable().Where(h => h.Field<string>("COLUMN 0") == val) 
        group row by row.Field<string>("COLUMN 2") 
        into sales 
        orderby sales.Key 
        select new 
        { 
            Name = sales.Key, 
            CountOfClients = sales.Sum(v => v.Field<int>("COLUMN 4")) 
        };
```

If your columns are actually strings, you'd need to write:

```
int.Parse(v.Field<string>("COLUMN 4"))
```

Comment: That worked...thanks a ton...I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!
I will accept your answer in 7 minutes due to time restraint.